# Vaadin Charts + Hibernate implementation

Tags: hibernate, charts, persistence, vaadin, add-on

I'm curious about this kinda mashup. I passed all Vaadin Charts tutorials, thats what i exactly need. The problem is - i dunno how to implement this addon using hibernate.

I know, there's an option using SQLContainer/JPA container, but it's not suitable for me

I'm planning to use MySQL

Please give some suggestions

Thank you ;)

Comment: I am not familar with Vaadin charts but with dCharts add on. The way to go there is to collect your data (e.g. from database) and then create the chart component which allows you to specify chart data. Can you clarify your question what the exact problem is?

Comment: Yes, sure. I'm thinking of using DAO pattern to access data. The problem is how to toss results it to Vaadin Charts. In tutorial clearly there's BeanItemCollection specified with static data usage.

Comment: Have you looked here? https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/-/Vaadin+Charts+Tutorial

Comment: Yes. I mentioned this @ topic start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `DAO` to get data using collection API and use it to fill the chart series.

For example, for a Timeline chart:

```
List<Series> series = new ArrayList<Series>();
Map<Date, Double> dataMap = dao.getDateValues();
series.add(createDateTimeSeries("Dates", dataMap));
chart.getConfiguration().setSeries(series);
chart.getConfiguration().setTitle("Some Title"));
chart.drawChart();

...

public DataSeries createDateTimeSeries(String name, Map<Date, ?extends Number> data) {
        DataSeries series = new DataSeries(name);
        List<Date> keys = new ArrayList<Date>(data.keySet());
        Collections.sort(keys);
        for (Date key : keys) {
            series.add(new DataSeriesItem(key, data.get(key)));
        }

        return series;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide sample project implementing this logic? This would help me alot. Thanks

Comment: No, I haven't. AFAIK Vaadin Charts license is not compatible with open source.

Comment: Hello, they provide 30 days trial for testing purposes. See: https://vaadin.com/charts